# What AWS service to use for very short EC2 spikes in Django app

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am running a Django app on AWS EC2 t3.large instance. When the user logs in for the first time, we sync their messages and a celery task is run on their SMS. This is a CPU intensive process, and lasts for not much long. Here is the [CPU utilization for last 3 days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19tvw.png). Basically, 2-3% on average, and upto 30-40% for a short while. How should I set up my infrastructure?

Comment: Can you maybe offload the syncing process to some dedicated worker? Depending on the length, it could be lambda, ecs container or separate instance?